# MySQL Retrieving DATA using BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table that looks like the one below named dtr.
I am having trouble in using BETWEEN query.
like:

```
$between = mysql_query("Select * from dtr where State Between 'Check In' And 'Check Out'");
```

What I want it to do is to also get the row with the STATE Out and Out Back inside the BETWEEN in Check In and Check Out. But it seems wont work. What else should i use? or do?
Because all i get it Check In and Check Out results.

```
   Name      | AC-No.|    Date   |    Time      |    State   | Exception| Operation
-------------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+----------
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/13/2013 | 11:45:18 PM  |  Check In  |   OK     |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 12:46:58 AM  |  Out       |   Out    |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 12:52:41 AM  |  Out Back  |   Out    |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 02:12:50 AM  |  Out       |   Out    |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 02:43:11 AM  |  Out Back  |   Out    |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 05:46:58 AM  |  Out       |   Out    |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 06:22:41 AM  |  Out Back  |   Out    |
Johnny Starks| 1220  | 5/14/2013 | 16:55:12 AM  |  Check Out |   OK     |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use query with `IN`

```
Select * from dtr 
where State IN('Check In','Check Out','Out','Out Back')
```

`BETWEEN` is mostly used with `date` and `numeric` data.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh! I want to add something.. I want to count every Pair of Out and Out Back inside EVERY Check In and Check Out.Like in the example above it has a 3 pair of Outs.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use string comparison for your range if:

```
'Check In' < 'Out' < 'Out Back' < 'Check Out'
```

So you have to use the `IN` operator and use grouping to count the number of individual occurrences of each state:

```
SELECT `State`, COUNT(*)
FROM dtr 
WHERE State IN ('Check In', 'Out', 'Out Back', 'Check Out')
GROUP BY `State`;
```

Result:

```
Check In  | 1
Out       | 3
Out Back  | 3
Check Out | 1
```

Comment: so should i use strtotime() to compare them four? I want to know if how can i only count the OUT and OUT BACK, let's say in your example OUT has 3 counts and OUT BACK has 3 counts in one pair of CHECK IN and CHECK OUT. Then i will sum the two which will be 6, and then end of it. Then again there will be another pair of CHECK In and CHECK OUT cause i used while loop for it, and will again do the same calculation as I have mentioned.

Comment: If you have multiple "check in" and "check out" groups, you will need some code outside of MySQL to perform the grouping for you. You can help that code by sorting on date/time of course.